# What is the point of the development tag?

Tags: discussion

Why do we even have the tag [development](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) on AE? Because questions about writing or publishing apps, or ROMs are off-topic here. The description of this tag even says "*Development questions are off-topic here, so don't ask them*".

Is there any possibility for a development question that would use this tag to be on-topic and perhaps overlap with [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That tag *ideally serves as a preemptive measure* to stop the off-topic question (about development/programming) from being posted. It is expected from a user that if not the wiki, the user would at least read the excerpt of the tag they intend to use in the question.

As the fate would have it, the existence of questions with that tag signify that some users do not prefer reading anything or acting on the suggestion provided by a tag at all.

Perhaps if there is a way for us to evaluate the practical usefulness of that tag, deletion or expansion of the tag may become a priority for Community.

Comment: If you go to the development tag page, some questions that use it are on-topic. Could this be an overlap?

Comment: It was also intended as a kind of "trap". Just check all questions using this tag, and VTC them :)

Comment: @TheBro21 We should probably re-tag any questions that are on-topic.  I don't think we particularly need a category about IDEs/editors/etc.  (Edit: I've now done this, apart from a couple questions that didn't really seem to be taggable with much else.)

Comment: I suggested an edit to the tag info. Probably not the best, and hopefully it can be expanded more. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: On stack overflow choosing [tag:homework] shows a pop-up "Homework questions are off-topic here". Maybe something similar could be done for this tag?